# R function to display if respondent answered yes to multiple choices

Tags: r, datatables, survey

I have responses to a survey where a respondent was asked to pick all options that apply. Each choice is treated like its own variable - where if you selected yes to the multiple-choice option they are given a 1 and if not selected they are given a 0.

I want to see if someone selected an option how many also picked option B or option c. Ideally, I want to create a table that shows the percentage of people who answered yes (01) to option MR1 and then also answered yes to option MR2 and MR3.

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID MR1 MR2 MR3
Person1 1 1 1
Person2 1 0 0
Person3 1 1 0", header = T, sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Ideally, I would like the output to look something like this - showing 100% of people who selected MR1 also selected MR1, 2/3 of people who selected MR1 also picked MR2 or MR3, and 1/3 of people who selected MR2 also picked MR3 -- this will be helpful to see if there are any MR options that are more likely to be grouped together than others.

Is there any code for something like this?

```
       MR1  MR2 MR3
MR1    1    0.66    0.66   
MR2   0.66    1    0.33  
MR3   0.66    0.33   1
```

Comment: See [Create a co-occurrence matrix from dummy-coded observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622730/create-a-co-occurrence-matrix-from-dummy-coded-observations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, with a bit different representation of results. In your case, you are only looking at pairs and not at all options that might be there.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(x = case_when(MR1 == 0 ~ "none",
                            MR1 == 1 & MR2 == 0 & MR3 == 0 ~ "one",
                            MR1 == 1 & MR2 == 1 & MR3 == 0 ~ "two-second",
                            MR1 == 1 & MR2 == 0 & MR3 == 1 ~ "two-third",
                            MR1 == 1 & MR2 == 1 & MR3 == 1 ~ "three"))

df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(answers = n()) %>% mutate(share = round(answers/sum(answers)*100))
```